# PIVOT and IF statement or conditional statement?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

From what I've read, I can only use `PIVOT` when I know the columns to show. Otherwise, I have to use dynamic sql:

```
select * into #another_table
from 
(
  select City, [month], [win-loss]
  from #final
) src
pivot
(
  min([win-loss])
  for month in ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5])
) piv;
```

In the query above, `for month in ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5])` refers to the month number, and in this particular query, `#final` has data from month 1-5.

Although I don't know how what months will be queried, I know that column `month` will have a maximum of twelve months.

Is it possible to insert an `IF` statement so that it considers any possible combination up to 12 months?

I prefer not using dynamic sql, unless there isn't an alternative.

`#final` looks like this. At least in this example, I know that there are rows for months 1-5, but the month numbers would be retrieved from this table:

```
City    month   win-loss
Houston 1       LOSS
Miami   2       WON
Orlando 3       WON
Reading 4       WON
```

Comment: This is going to take dynamic SQL I'm fairly certain, but it isn't a bad thing in this case. Since you aren't accepting any parameters into your dynamic SQL, you don't have to worry about SQL Injection, and dynamic SQL in this case wouldn't be a performance burden.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to insert an IF inside a single statement.   The way you can use IF to avoid dynamic sql is like this (psuedocode):

```
IF A = true
  {SELECT Query A}
ELSE IF B = true
  {SELECT Query B}
ELSE IF ...
```